# Has the use of the idiom "last week" surpassed the use of the correct "yester-week"?

Tags: word-choice, time, language-evolution, this-last

In his book *Write It Right*, which was published in 1909 -– a hundred years ago -- Ambrose Bierce disagreed with the usage of the words “Last” and “Past” with “week”. He explained :

> Last and Past.  “Last week.” “The past
>   week.” Neither is accurate: a week
>   cannot be the last if another is
>   already begun; and all weeks except
>   this one are past. Here two wrongs
>   seem to make a right: we can say the
>   week last past. But will we? I trow
>   not.

And H. W. Fowler agreed with those sentiments in his Fowler's *Modern English Usage 1st Ed*.

> 4. Last) (latest. In this now favourite antithesis (Dr Marshall's
>   latest, but we hope not his last,
>   contribution) we are reminded that
>   latest means last up to now only,
>   whereas last does not exclude the
>   future. The distinction is a
>   convenient one, & the use of latest
>   for last is described by the OED as '
>   now archaic & poetical'. But no
>   corresponding agreement has yet been
>   reached for abstaining from last when
>   latest would be the more precise word,
>   & many idioms militate against it
>   (last Tuesday; last year ; for the
>   last fortnight; on the last occasion ;
>   as I said in my last).

And his successor, R. W. Burchfield, also agreed, in *New Folwer's Modern English Usage 3rd Ed.*

> 4. Last/Latest. In such a
>   context as “In his latest book, Dr.
>   A…”, it is clear that Dr. A has
>   written earlier books and that he is
>   still alive and may well write others.
>   If the statement runs “In his last
>   book, Dr A…” the meaning could be the
>   same, or it could also imply that this
>   was the final book written by Dr A
>   before he died. It is obvious,
>   therefore, that if there is any danger
>   of contextual ambiguity some word
>   other than last should be used. In
>   many idiomatic phrases last is still
>   the only possible adj. of the two: =
>   most recent; next before a specified
>   time ( last Christmas; last week); =
>   preceding; previous in a series ( got
>   on at the last station); = only
>   remaining ( the last biscuit; our last
>   chance); ( preceded by the) = the
>   least likely or suitable ( the last
>   person I’d want to see; the last thing
>   I’d have expected; = the lowest in
>   order ( the last name on the list).

Nevertheless, the *Oxford English Dictionary 2nd Ed* described *yester* as:

> yester-
>
> in comb. or as prefix = immediately
>   preceding the present, last, in
>   yestereve, etc., after yesterday,
>   yesternight; e.g. yester-afternoon,
>   yester-age, yester-noon,
>   yester-tempest, yester-week. See also
>   yester-year.

Of course, I admit I've always thought that *last week* was the week before this.

So my question is: Do you think that use of the idiom *last week* has overpowered the correct usage "yester-week"?

Comment: Since *nobody* says "yester-week" nowadays, I would say the answer is rather obvious. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RegDwight Nobody says "This is I" evenwhen it's called for.

Comment: This does not seem like an answerable question, but an invitation to discussion.  Clearly, nobody uses *yester-week*, and few are even aware it ever existed.  I think this discussion is better suited for the EL&U [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: Some do say "this is I"; "yester-" is different.

Comment: Although not completely clear, this question is still a serious and answerable question: *there was a situation x; did a situation y precede this? Is that what writers a, b, and c are observing?*. The problem is mostly that the OP assumed a premise that isn't true, namely x. But adjusting premises is also part of the job... I vote to reopen.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: This is hardly “ambiguous, vague, incomplete…”; it’s very clear, and pretty well-documented.  Rather, it’s a [loaded question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question), like the classic “Do you still beat your wife?”: as Cerberus says, it implicitly assumes a false premise.  This doesn’t seem to me to fall under the ‘not a real question’ guidelines: such questions can be appropriately answered by pointing out the errors in their premises, as several of us have below.  Would vote to reopen if I could :-P

Comment: @Cerberus, @PLL: Okay, reopened.  Let's see what people do with it. I still think this question seems extremely chatty. The actual question is completely trivial, and appears to be there for no other reason than to get around the fact that it is a discussion.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: In logic that's called the fallacy of complex question.

Comment: After reading PLL's and Cerberus's answers and comments, I realised that my belief was indeed bulit on a false premise. Please pardon me on my ignorance and false belief. It's a really eye opener and I hope again hope if I ever come out with this kind of questions again you would able to clear my doubt and enlighten me.

Comment: I'm going to start using yesterweek. What a great sounding word!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### **Yes.**

It’s very tempting to leave the answer at that, but… some more notes.

1. The most cursory look at any newspaper, or around the blogosphere, confirms this answer.  ‘Last week’ is common as muck, while ‘yester-week’ is virtually non-existent, and when it does appear, it’s for archaic effect.
2. ‘Last week’ isn’t in any way incorrect.  It’s had the meaning ‘most recent, latest’ for over 600 years: in 1411, for instance, the rolls of Parliament under Henry IV refer to “The last parlement…”  ([OED](http://www.oed.com).)
3. As your sources point out, however, ‘last’ can sometimes be ambiguous, and ‘latest’ is often a good alternative in those cases.  Talking about ‘the latest week’ sounds odd and affected, just as it did when Fowler wrote; but talking about ‘Madonna’s latest single’ is perfectly fine.
4. ‘Yester-’ isn’t actually as archaic as we tend to think!  A few examples — ‘yesterday’, ‘yesternight’, ‘yester-eve’ — are old, but (according to the OED again) the general combining form (in eg ‘yester-week’) only really shows up in the 19th century.  Amazingly, even good old ‘yester-year’ was apparently only coined in 1870, by Rosetti translating Villon: “Where are the snows of yester-year?”
5. Finally, *none* of the sources you give support your implication that ‘yester-week’ is the correct usage that should be preferred to ‘last week’! The Bierce and Fowler quotes point out the illogic and occasional ambiguity of ‘last’ (note that neither of these makes it grammatically wrong); Fowler’s suggests ‘latest’ as a sometimes better alternative, but neither even mentions ‘yester-’!  The OED simply points out that ‘yester-’ exists (at least, existed for a few decades) and means roughly the same thing.

Comment: Excellent points. I suspect that "yester-year", if it was coined in 1870, was never anything but a jocular or affected word. Perhaps many more of the expressions that sound old now were never actually current.

Comment: @Cerberus: Indeed — given the subject-matter of [the poem in question](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ballade_des_dames_du_temps_jadis), I suspect Rosetti was already going for the archaic associations in coining ‘yester-year’, presumably thinking of ‘yesternight’, ‘yester-eve’ which were already old-fashioned in his day.

Comment: Very good explanation !

Answer (score 4):

I think you are misinterpreting Fowler. When he says "many idioms militate against it (*last Tuesday; last year ; for the last fortnight; on the last occasion ; as I said in my last*)", he means that these are the only correct forms, even though they clash with certain expectations of logic. Burchfield agrees: "In many idiomatic phrases last is still the only possible adj. of the two: = most recent; next before a specified time ( last Christmas; last week)".

The fact that some idiom is illogical or ambiguous does not mean that it should be changed; indeed, it should be kept here, say Fowler and Burchfield. I know this because I have read enough of their opinions to be sure.

I am not sure whether Bierce means to say "it is illogical and it should be changed" or "it is illogical but it is idiom and therefore we should keep it"; but his "Here two wrongs seem to make a right: we can say the week last past. But will we? **I trow not**." seems to indicate that he did not advocate a change of universal idiom either, illogical though it may be. He appears to say "this would be logical, but we will not use it, simply because we have long traditions of usage".

Words like "yester-week" were not even current around 1900, and now they are even less so; "last week" is and was the right way to say it. I see no other option.

Comment: As always in English, tradition trumps logic.

Comment: @Orbling: Exactly! This language sucks.

Comment: @Cerberus: Logic I like; but I like tradition better. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: Cue me proposing to demolish all medieval churches for being illogical.

Comment: @Cerberus: The church buildings are lovely, better than any modern tat.  It's just the people inside them that are illogical, demolish them.

Comment: @Orbling: That, and the fact that they take up valuable space while nobody ever visits them.

Comment: @Cerberus: I think we discussed the old building issue before.  I would rather a beautiful empty building in one place, than a horrible used one over its grave.  Too much of that in London as is.

Comment: @Orbling: I do hope you haven't forgotten that I was 100% ironic that time as well? Old things good. New things bad.

Comment: @Cerberus: Aye, now I remember the relief I felt last time, LOL.

Answer (score 1):

The word *yester-week* is entirely obsolete today. Using it in contemporary English is not a mark of correctness, but of insanity.

This was largely the case even in the time of Mr. Bierce, which is what makes his illogical and ill-informed screed so funny.

Comment: poor Bierce may not be quite as degraded as the uses to which this questioner would put him.  He doesn’t even mention ‘yester-’ in this quote; and (though I don’t know the context, so I may be wrong) it could fit just as well into “Ha, look at the illogical vagaries of our languages; aren’t they fascinating and beautiful?” as into “Ugh!  This is Illogical and Must be Reformed!”

Comment: @PLL: I think that's it.

Comment: One maid’s insanity is the next one’s poetry.  And vice versa.